# WordPress MySQL select query to filter every post content that contains img tags without src attribute or an empty src

Tags: html, mysql, sql, wordpress

## Issue

In order to determine the posts that contain `img` tags in their post content, but, without `img` `src` or the `src` attribute is not appear at all.

I tried to find a solution for selecting all post contents by apply the following criteria:

The `img` tag is a must to be appeared.

**every post content must have html `img` tag without `src`, or at least with empty `src` like `<img src=""`**

The below is what I have used to accomplish this task

```sql
SELECT
  ID, post_title, post_content 
FROM 
  wp_posts 
WHERE 
  post_content LIKE('%<img % src=""%')
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

## Question

The previous solution worked as expected, but, I am looking for a better solution maybe using regular expression, because I think I have missed the post contents that contains `img` tags without `src` at all for example.

I am trying to target all possible cases that accespt the previous criteria.

## Sample Post Content Results

```html
<p align="center" style="text-align: center;">
  <img title="%2525ED%252599%252594%2525EB%2525B3%2525B4%2525EC%2525A7%252591%2B%2525ED%252591%25259C%2525EC%2525A7%252580%2B%2525EC%252597%252585%2525EB%2525A1%25259C%2525EB%252593%25259C.jpg" src="">
</p>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  What does "empty src" mean?

Comment: Why are you doing a `CONCAT` on two string literals, the result of which is `'%<img %src=""%'`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Judging by the SQL, probably `<img src=""`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I will support my question with some desired results.
"empty src" there are cases that the src attribute appears but without a link to an image.

Comment: @Booboo You are right there is no need for `CONCAT` I will update my question regarding your note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it with regular expressions would require *lookahead assertions*, which MySql doesn't support. Judging by your SQL it appears that the  `<img>` tag and `src` attribute when present are always lowercase (if not, see below), then the following might work:

```
SELECT
  ID, post_title, post_content 
FROM 
  wp_posts 
WHERE post_content LIKE '%<img %src=""%'
    OR (INSTR(post_content,'<img') <> 0  AND INSTR(post_content, 'src') = 0)
ORDER BY ID DESC;
```

If uppercase might be used for the `<img>` tag or `src` attribute, then wherever `post_content` appears in the `WHERE` clause in the above SQL, replace it with `LOWER(post_content)`.

[For what it's worth, this is the Regex I would be using if MySql supported it](https://regex101.com/r/npcQKg/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much @Booboo for your answer. Now I can target `img` tags without `src`.